# Preserving the appearance of CSS flow while switching position from relative to fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm wondering what's the best way to deal with this: I have two `div` in document flow (nav + content), positioned as `relative`.

In some situations, I will need to give the nav a `fixed` position. As this removes the nav from the flow, the content div is no longer properly located below. I could add the content some `top-margin` to compensate, but this would have to be computed because the nav doesn't have a set height (in my example, it's 50% of the window height).

Any suggestion?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gkVS/

Comment: If you're using jQuery to toggle the class, why not to calculate the height of the fixed element and set the proper margin to the other one via JavaScript then? Is that only for demonstration?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I prefer to avoid it if somebody can think of a pure html+css solution.

Comment: So you always want both to be 50% height?

Comment: Here is a dynamic fixed header... but I found issues on page-load-between navigation, where it jumped a little:   http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/gabJr

And here is another fixed header that only kicks in if modernizr detects that there is no touch: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/qKLIo

Comment: - Not answers... but some things to think about.

Comment: @sheriffderek: no, only the top one is 50%, but it is only for the sake of the case study. You don't know in advance its absolute height.

Comment: Quite simply, you're gonna have to use either jQuery/Javascript or css calc().  The issue with CSS calc() is compatibility...  http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc  IE and Mobile support is shoddy at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to calculate a number and apply somewhere else, is javaScript, because you have to find that number after the DOM is loaded.

I'm going to just say that as of (this date) you shouldn't be using fixed positioning at all without testing for touch with modernizr, and only in the case that it's "no-touch" use fixed, due to the less that adequate browser support on mobile and touch enabled desktop. Try one out at a store and you'll see what I mean. Jumpy weird fixed headers everywhere.

The fact that your divs are relative doesn't really matter.

The best thing to do, is run modernizr. It will spit out a no-touch class on your html that you can use to style with.

```
.no-touch nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Then with jQuery, you can do something along these lines - if you are using box-sizing: border-box (which I suggest) than you'll want to use '.outerHeight()' to be sure to include padding and borders. You'll also only want a fixed header when the screen is big enough to accommodate it.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var navHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

if ( windowHeight > 600 ) {
   $('nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
   $('section').css('margin-top', navHeight); 
}
```

Here is [a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Djf7T/) I hope that helps. Sorry there is no way to do it with CSS yet. That would be cool.